Backtrader cerebro.plot() function not returning any plots in Spyder
I have taken some sample code that downloads stock data, runs it through a trading strategy using Backtrader's cerebro function. When I run the cerebro.plot() function, no chart is returned (either in-line or as a pop-up window). The code for this is below:
import backtrader as bt

# Define a simple moving average crossover strategy
class SMACrossOver(bt.Strategy):
    params = (('short_period', 10), ('long_period', 30))

    def __init__(self):
        self.short_ma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(
            self.data.close, period=self.params.short_period)
        self.long_ma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(
            self.data.close, period=self.params.long_period)

    def next(self):
        if self.short_ma > self.long_ma:
            self.buy()
        elif self.short_ma < self.long_ma:
            self.sell()

# Create a cerebro engine
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

data = yf.download('AAPL', start='2020-01-01', end='2022-01-01')

# Convert data to backtrader format
data_bt = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=data)

cerebro.adddata(data_bt)

# Add strategy
cerebro.addstrategy(SMACrossOver)

# Add a broker with a cash fund for the initial capital
cerebro.broker.set_cash(100000)

# Add commission - This is for illustrative purposes and can be modified as needed
cerebro.broker.setcommission(commission=0.001)

# Add the analyzers
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.SharpeRatio, _name='sharpe')
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.DrawDown, _name='drawdown')

# Run the backtest
strategies = cerebro.run()

# Print the results
strat = strategies[0]
print('Sharpe Ratio:', strat.analyzers.sharpe.get_analysis()['sharperatio'])
print('Max Drawdown:', strat.analyzers.drawdown.get_analysis()['max']['drawdown'])

# Plot the results
cerebro.plot()

The only output from the console is shown below:
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Sharpe Ratio: 1.545255702414604
Max Drawdown: 3.1184551599840895
<IPython.core.display.Javascript object>
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>

[[<Figure size 432x288 with 4 Axes>]]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Have tried plotting with iline set to True and False, no difference. Can't find much more information out there on this issue.

Struggled with this too, but found a solution that works for me. Just change the code to:
{
 cerebro.run()
 cerebro.plot(iplot=False)
}

make sure the Spyder graphics backend is on 'automatic'.

Thank you. It took me a while to find this solution. Works perfectly.

Configure IPython Console for Inline Display
Spyder uses an IPython console which can be configured to display plots inline:
Open Spyder, go to Tools > Preferences.
Navigate to IPython console > Graphics.
In the "Graphics backend" section, select "Inline".
Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes.
Restart Spyder to ensure the changes take effect
